# Spritekit game in swift: how to keep a score variable the same when game reloads, instead of going back to initial value?

Tags: swift

I am building a simple game, to keep track of the score I simply use a `score` variable which is initially `var score = 1`, then this is incremented by 1 when the player scores. Problem is when the game switches screens for a second (I have a short SKTransition scene when the player wins) and then is taken back to the main GameScene.swift file, the `var score = 1` line will be read again, thus changing the score variable back to 1 (when it was 2 just after the player scored).

As someone with very little experience I am stumped on how I can deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the score to stay just for that session of play, you can just pass it as a parameter to your GameScene

for example:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var score: Int = 0

    init(size: CGSize, score: Int) {
        self.score = score
        super.init(size: size)
    }
```

then when you want to transition

```
let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size, score: self.score)
self.view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.3))
```

Comment: That works, also just needed to add  '   required init!(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }' under the init code.

Comment: if it helped you, please click checkbox next to my answer to mark as correct :)